# Need help building debhelper 10.2.2-bpo8 from source

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, debuild

I'm trying to build debhelper from the tar.xz file at https://packages.debian.org/source/stable-backports/debhelper.  I've satisfied all its dependencies and ran the makefile in ./debhelper/lib successfully to be sure.  I then opened a terminal in ./debhelper, ran the makefile successfully, then tried to run `debuild -us -uc`.  However it spits:

```
devonc@devongaming:~/Downloads/debhelper$ debuild -us -uc
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package debhelper
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 10.2.2~bpo8+1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution jessie-backports
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Niels Thykier <niels@thykier.net>
 dpkg-source --before-build debhelper
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
./run dh clean --no-parallel --without autoreconf
   dh_auto_clean
    make -j1 clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
rm -f *.1 *.7 Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Version.pm
po4a --previous --rm-translations --rm-backups man/po4a/po4a.cfg
for lang in es pt fr de; do \
    if [ -e man/$lang ]; then rmdir man/$lang; fi; \
done;
rmdir: failed to remove 'man/es': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove 'man/pt': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove 'man/fr': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove 'man/de': Directory not empty
Makefile:88: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make[1]: ** * [clean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
dh_auto_clean: make -j1 clean returned exit code 2
debian/rules:14: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
devonc@devongaming:~/Downloads/debhelper$
```

at me.  If I run `sudo debuild -us -uc` I get:

```
devonc@devongaming:~/Downloads/debhelper$ sudo debuild -us -uc
[sudo] password for devonc: 
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: source package debhelper
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 10.2.2~bpo8+1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution jessie-backports
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Niels Thykier <niels@thykier.net>
 dpkg-source --before-build debhelper
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
./run dh clean --no-parallel --without autoreconf
   dh_auto_clean
    make -j1 clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
rm -f *.1 *.7 Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Version.pm
po4a --previous --rm-translations --rm-backups man/po4a/po4a.cfg
for lang in es pt fr de; do \
    if [ -e man/$lang ]; then rmdir man/$lang; fi; \
done;
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b debhelper
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (native)'
dpkg-source: info: building debhelper in debhelper_10.2.2~bpo8+1.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: building debhelper in debhelper_10.2.2~bpo8+1.dsc
 debian/rules build
./run dh build --no-parallel --without autoreconf
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
    make -j1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
printf "package Debian::Debhelper::Dh_Version;\n\$version='10.2.2~bpo8+1';\n1" > \
    Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Version.pm
cat debhelper.pod | \
    perl -e ' undef $/; foreach (@ARGV) { open (IN, $_) or die "$_: $!"; $file=<IN>; close IN; if ($file=~m/=head1 .*?\n\n(.*?) - (.*?)\n\n/s) { my $item="=item $1(1)\n\n$2\n\n"; if (" dh_installmanpages " !~ / $1 /) { $list.=$item; } else { $list_deprecated.=$item; } } } END { while (<STDIN>) { s/#LIST#/$list/; s/#LIST_DEPRECATED#/$list_deprecated/; print; }; }' dh_auto_build dh_auto_clean dh_auto_configure dh_auto_install dh_auto_test dh_bugfiles dh_builddeb dh_clean dh_compress dh_fixperms dh_gconf dh_gencontrol dh_icons dh_install dh_installcatalogs dh_installchangelogs dh_installcron dh_installdeb dh_installdebconf dh_installdirs dh_installdocs dh_installemacsen dh_installexamples dh_installgsettings dh_installifupdown dh_installinfo dh_installinit dh_installlogcheck dh_installlogrotate dh_installman dh_installmanpages dh_installmenu dh_installmime dh_installmodules dh_installpam dh_installppp dh_installudev dh_installwm dh_installxfonts dh_link dh_lintian dh_listpackages dh_makeshlibs dh_md5sums dh_movefiles dh_perl dh_prep dh_shlibdeps dh_strip dh_systemd_enable dh_systemd_start dh_testdir dh_testroot dh_ucf dh_update_autotools_config dh_usrlocal | \
    pod2man --utf8 -c Debhelper -r "10.2.2~bpo8+1" --name="debhelper" --section=7  > debhelper.7
pod2man --utf8 -c Debhelper -r "10.2.2~bpo8+1" --name="debhelper" --section=7 debhelper-obsolete-compat.pod > debhelper-obsolete-compat.7
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm /100 -name "dh*" \
    -exec pod2man --utf8 -c Debhelper -r "10.2.2~bpo8+1" {} {}.1 \;
po4a --previous -L UTF-8 man/po4a/po4a.cfg 
Discard man/de/debhelper-obsolete-compat.pod (39 of 49 strings; only 79.59% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/debhelper.pod (186 of 258 strings; only 72.09% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/debhelper-obsolete-compat.pod (39 of 49 strings; only 79.59% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/dh_clean.pod (20 of 28 strings; only 71.42% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/dh_install.pod (34 of 45 strings; only 75.55% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/dh_installinit.pod (42 of 56 strings; only 75% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/dh_strip.pod (24 of 43 strings; only 55.81% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/dh_systemd_enable.pod (9 of 26 strings; only 34.61% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/dh_systemd_start.pod (11 of 25 strings; only 44% translated; need 80%).
Discard man/es/strings-kept-translations.pod (0 of 1 strings; only 0% translated; need 80%).
set -e; \
for lang in es pt fr de; do \
    dir=man/$lang; \
    for file in $dir/dh*.pod; do \
        prog=`basename $file | sed 's/.pod//'`; \
        pod2man --utf8 -c Debhelper -r "10.2.2~bpo8+1" $file $prog.$lang.1; \
    done; \
    if [ -e $dir/debhelper.pod ]; then \
        cat $dir/debhelper.pod | \
            perl -e ' undef $/; foreach (@ARGV) { open (IN, $_) or die "$_: $!"; $file=<IN>; close IN; if ($file=~m/=head1 .*?\n\n(.*?) - (.*?)\n\n/s) { my $item="=item $1(1)\n\n$2\n\n"; if (" dh_installmanpages " !~ / $1 /) { $list.=$item; } else { $list_deprecated.=$item; } } } END { while (<STDIN>) { s/#LIST#/$list/; s/#LIST_DEPRECATED#/$list_deprecated/; print; }; }' `find $dir -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "dh_*.pod" | LC_ALL=C sort` | \
            pod2man --utf8 -c Debhelper -r "10.2.2~bpo8+1" --name="debhelper" --section=7 > debhelper.$lang.7; \
    fi; \
    if [ -e $dir/debhelper-obsolete-compat.pod ]; then \
        pod2man --utf8 -c Debhelper -r "10.2.2~bpo8+1" --name="debhelper" --section=7 $dir/debhelper-obsolete-compat.pod > debhelper-obsolete-compat.$lang.7; \
    fi; \
done
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
   dh_auto_test
    make -j1 test
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
printf "package Debian::Debhelper::Dh_Version;\n\$version='10.2.2~bpo8+1';\n1" > \
    Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Version.pm
./run perl -MTest::Harness -e 'runtests grep { ! /CVS/ && ! /\.svn/ && -f && -x } @ARGV' t/* t/*/*
t/dh-lib.t .......................... ok
t/dh_compress.t ..................... ok
t/dh_install.t ...................... ok
t/dh_link.t ......................... ok
t/maintscript.t ..................... ok
t/override_target.t ................. ok
t/pod.t ............................. ok
t/size.t ............................ ok
t/syntax.t .......................... ok
t/buildsystems/buildsystem_tests.t .. ok
t/dh_installdocs/dh_installdocs.t ... ok
All tests successful.
Files=11, Tests=616,  7 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.00 sys +  1.88 cusr  0.12 csys =  2.06 CPU)
Result: PASS
-# clean up log etc
./run dh_clean
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
./run dh binary --no-parallel --without autoreconf
   dh_testroot
   dh_prep
   debian/rules override_dh_auto_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
./run dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/debhelper
    make -j1 install DESTDIR=/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper AM_UPDATE_INFO_DIR=no
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
install -d /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/bin \
    /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts \
    /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Sequence \
    /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Buildsystem
install dh dh_auto_build dh_auto_clean dh_auto_configure dh_auto_install dh_auto_test dh_bugfiles dh_builddeb dh_clean dh_compress dh_fixperms dh_gconf dh_gencontrol dh_icons dh_install dh_installcatalogs dh_installchangelogs dh_installcron dh_installdeb dh_installdebconf dh_installdirs dh_installdocs dh_installemacsen dh_installexamples dh_installgsettings dh_installifupdown dh_installinfo dh_installinit dh_installlogcheck dh_installlogrotate dh_installman dh_installmanpages dh_installmenu dh_installmime dh_installmodules dh_installpam dh_installppp dh_installudev dh_installwm dh_installxfonts dh_link dh_lintian dh_listpackages dh_makeshlibs dh_md5sums dh_movefiles dh_perl dh_prep dh_shlibdeps dh_strip dh_systemd_enable dh_systemd_start dh_testdir dh_testroot dh_ucf dh_update_autotools_config dh_usrlocal /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/bin
install -m 0644 autoscripts/* /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts
install -m 0644 Debian/Debhelper/*.pm /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper
[ "/usr" = /usr ] || \
    sed -i '/$prefix=/s@/usr@/usr@g' /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm
install -m 0644 Debian/Debhelper/Sequence/*.pm /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Sequence
install -m 0644 Debian/Debhelper/Buildsystem/*.pm /home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper/debian/debhelper/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Buildsystem
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/devonc/Downloads/debhelper'
   dh_installdocs
   dh_installchangelogs
   dh_installexamples
   dh_installman
   dh_perl
   dh_link
   dh_compress
   dh_fixperms
   dh_installdeb
   dh_gencontrol
   dh_md5sums
   dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package 'debhelper' in '../debhelper_10.2.2~bpo8+1_all.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package 'dh-systemd' in '../dh-systemd_10.2.2~bpo8+1_all.deb'.
 dpkg-genchanges  >../debhelper_10.2.2~bpo8+1_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: including full source code in upload
 dpkg-source --after-build debhelper
dpkg-buildpackage: full upload; Debian-native package (full source is included)
Now running lintian...
warning: the authors of lintian do not recommend running it with root privileges!
E: debhelper changes: bad-distribution-in-changes-file jessie-backports
Finished running lintian.
devonc@devongaming:~/Downloads/debhelper$
```

Debuild and sudo debuild also get the same errors respectively.

I'm running Linux Lite 3.2 (based on Ubuntu 16.04).  This is the second time I've ever tried to build something from source, so please explain to me as you would a beginner.

This is also only my third time ever posting to askubuntu (from a new account this time; deactivated the email for the old one), so if I need to edit the formatting on anything please let me know.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50649/discussion-on-question-by-devon-c-need-help-building-debhelper-10-2-2-bpo8-from).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xenial already has [debhelper 10.2.2 in the backports repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-backports/debhelper). You could install it from there.

1. Open `software-properties-gtk` →  Update tab → Enable unsupported updates (xenial-backports)

   Or add this line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   ```
2. Update package list

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Check available version of both packages

   `apt-cache policy debhelper dh-autoreconf`

   ```
   debhelper:
     Installed: 9.20160115ubuntu3
     Candidate: 9.20160115ubuntu3
     Version table:
        10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1 100
           100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
           100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
    *** 9.20160115ubuntu3 500
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   dh-autoreconf:
     Installed: 11
     Candidate: 11
     Version table:
        12~ubuntu16.04.1 100
           100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
           100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
    *** 11 500
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
4. Force installing the version from backports repo as it have low priority.

   ```
   sudo apt install dh-autoreconf=12~ubuntu16.04.1 debhelper=10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1
   ```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect for me. I already had the backports in my sources, so I only needed to force installing the different version.